# Dúvida com comando for no sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Tenho a seguinte situação, 5 campos de desconto que recebem o nome de desconto 01 até 05.
esta consulta sql funciona a baixo (1), faz o cálculo correto mais só quando tem apenas 1 dos descontos preenchidos, se eu tiver mais de 1 então o resultado não vai ficar correto.
Para que o resultado fique correto caso tenha mais de 1 desconto, eu preciso encontra o valor individual de cada desconto sobre o valor do preço é aí após isso eu teria um desconto global sobre o valor, eu poderia somar todos os descontos, eu teria que fazer um for é calcular cada um separado.

Como eu poderia fazer isso? agradeço!

```html
DECLARE @VALOR_ENCONTRADO1 real
DECLARE @VALOR_ENCONTRADO2 real
DECLARE @VALOR_ENCONTRADO3 real
DECLARE @VALOR_ENCONTRADO4 real
DECLARE @VALOR_ENCONTRADO5 real

@VALOR_ENCONTRADO1 =(DESCONTO01  / 100) * PRECO  
@VALOR_ENCONTRADO2 =(DESCONTO02  / 100) * PRECO  
@VALOR_ENCONTRADO3 =(DESCONTO03  / 100) * PRECO  
@VALOR_ENCONTRADO4 =(DESCONTO04  / 100) * PRECO  
@VALOR_ENCONTRADO5 =(DESCONTO05  / 100) * PRECO  

(1)
select 
case (ADICIONAL_ESTADO)  
  when 'S' then   (SUM(DESCONTO01 + DESCONTO02 + DESCONTO03 + DESCONTO04 + 0 ) / 100) * PRECO    
  when 'N' then   (SUM(DESCONTO01 + DESCONTO02 + DESCONTO03 + DESCONTO04+DESCONTO05) / 100)  * PRECO
END AS  VALOR_LIQUIDO, 

case (ADICIONAL_ESTADO)  
  when 'S' then  (SUM(DESCONTO01 + DESCONTO02 + DESCONTO03 + DESCONTO04 + 0 ) / 100 ) * PROMOCAO 
  when 'N' then  (SUM(DESCONTO01 + DESCONTO02 + DESCONTO03 + DESCONTO04+DESCONTO05) / 100 ) * PROMOCAO
END AS VALOR_PROMOCAO, 
IDPRODUTO,CODIGO,PRECO,DESCONTO01,DESCONTO02,DESCONTO03,DESCONTO04,DESCONTO05
from TB_PRODUTO
WHERE CODIGO = '016055IR'
GROUP BY ADICIONAL_ESTADO, IDPRODUTO,CODIGO, PRECO,PROMOCAO,DESCONTO01,DESCONTO02,DESCONTO03,DESCONTO04,DESCONTO05
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sql após a postagem da resposta:

```html
select 
(DESCONTO01 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_01,
(DESCONTO02 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_02,
(DESCONTO03 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_03,
(DESCONTO04 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_04,

case (ADICIONAL_ESTADO )  
  when 'S' then   (0 / 100 ) * PRECO   --0 é o valor do desconto para o estado caso tenha vai receber um valor
END AS DESCONTO_PRECO_05,  

(DESCONTO01 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_01,
(DESCONTO02 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_02,
(DESCONTO03 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_03,
(DESCONTO04 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_04,
case (ADICIONAL_ESTADO )  
  when 'N' then   (DESCONTO05 / 100 ) * PRECO    -- se não tem desconto para o estado vai receber o campo de desconto05 
END AS DESCONTO_PRECO_05,  

IDPRODUTO,CODIGO,PRECO,DESCONTO01,DESCONTO02,DESCONTO03,DESCONTO04,DESCONTO05
from TB_PRODUTO
WHERE CODIGO = '016055IR'
GROUP BY ADICIONAL_ESTADO, IDPRODUTO,CODIGO, PRECO,PROMOCAO,DESCONTO01,DESCONTO02,DESCONTO03,DESCONTO04,DESCONTO05
```

Imagem Resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a pergunta um pouco confusa (rs), e seria bom ver a estrutura das tabelas, mas espero que eu possa ajudar. Para encontrar o valor individual de cada desconto, você poderia fazer assim:

```
select 
(DESCONTO01 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_01,
(DESCONTO02 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_02,
(DESCONTO03 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_03,
(DESCONTO04 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_04,
case (ADICIONAL_ESTADO)     
  when 'N' then   (DESCONTO05 / 100)  * PRECO ,
END AS DESCONTO_PRECO_05, 

(DESCONTO01 / 100 ) * PROMOCAO AS DESCONTO_PROMOCAO_01,
(DESCONTO02 / 100 ) * PROMOCAO AS DESCONTO_PROMOCAO_02,
(DESCONTO03 / 100 ) * PROMOCAO AS DESCONTO_PROMOCAO_03,
(DESCONTO04 / 100 ) * PROMOCAO AS DESCONTO_PROMOCAO_04,
case (ADICIONAL_ESTADO)  
   when 'N' then  (DESCONTO05 / 100 ) * PROMOCAO
END AS DESCONTO_PROMOCAO_05, 

IDPRODUTO, CODIGO, PRECO, DESCONTO01, DESCONTO02, DESCONTO03, DESCONTO04, DESCONTO05
from TB_PRODUTO
  WHERE CODIGO = '016055IR'
GROUP BY ADICIONAL_ESTADO, IDPRODUTO, CODIGO, PRECO, PROMOCAO, DESCONTO01, DESCONTO02, DESCONTO03, DESCONTO04, DESCONTO05
```

Nesta consulta está apenas exibindo o valores de desconto, mas, a partir daí, é só fazer as operações desejadas para encontrar o seu "desconto global".

Comment: A sua ajuda foi fundamental, agradeço, mais eu ajustei a pergunta com a imagem e sql final do ajuste, é gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar o valor do desconto no mesmo campo, visto que veio em campos separados

Comment: Sim. É só substituir a virgula que separa os campos pelo sinal de mais (+). Desta forma, vai somar todos os descontos. Por exemplo:

select 
(DESCONTO01 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_01 +
(DESCONTO02 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_02 +
(DESCONTO03 / 100 ) * PRECO AS DESCONTO_PRECO_03 +
...

Comment: não deu muito certo porque DESCONTO_PRECO_01 não existe, mais agradeço mesmo assim.

Comment: use o isnull.
Ex: IsNull(DESCONTO_PRECO_01, 0)

Vai retornar 0 se o valor do campo for null.

Comment: desculpa a minha falta mais eu não conseguir usar de forma que ficasse correto. Se você conseguir altera a sua resposta eu agradeço.